# How to club dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I've two dictionaries as below.

```
d1 = {
       "user1":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},
       "user2":{"key3":"val3","key4":"val4"}
     }

d2 = { "admin":{
      "user1":{"key5":"val5","key6":"val6"},
      "user3":{"key7":"val7","key8":"val8"}
                }
     }
```

Final dictionary should look like this:

```
d3 = {
              "user1":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key5":"val5","key6":"val6"},
              "user2":{"key3":"val3","key4":"val4"},
               "user3":{"key7":"val7","key8":"val8"}
              }
```

Merging concept doesn't apply here. Could you please help me here ?

I've tried the solution of [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) . Below solution is different from what i needed.

```
{'admin': {'user3': {'key8': 'val8', 'key7': 'val7'}, 'user1': {'key6': 'val6',
'key5': 'val5'}}, 'user2': {'key3': 'val3', 'key4': 'val4'}, 'user1': {'key2': '
val2', 'key1': 'val1'}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: And what happens in case of duplicated keys?

Comment: @DeepSpace : Can you look at recent posted output which i've tried and what exactly id needed.

Comment: You should only regard `d2['admin']`, then you problem becomes more symmetric and natural.

Comment: Yeah Elazar. Got it. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a copy of the first dictionary, then iterate over the other - creating a default empty dictionary, then updating it with the contents of d2, eg:

```
d3 = d1.copy()
for k, v in d2['admin'].iteritems():
    d3.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
```

Gives you output of:

```
{'user1': {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key5': 'val5', 'key6': 'val6'},
 'user2': {'key3': 'val3', 'key4': 'val4'},
 'user3': {'key7': 'val7', 'key8': 'val8'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What does setdefault do here ?

Comment: @User See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault